# set quantity back to 1 when I open a different product

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cart, shopping-cart

I have this silly and weird issue I am trying to over come but as there are no errors i don't know which part of my code should i paste here.

The issue i want to solve is the product quantity does not update back to 1 once i move to a different product page after adding current product to the cart

the issue can also be seen in the tutorial video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mOkFXyxfsU&t=565s

around at 2:35:44 to 2:35:51

Product A quantity 5
Product B quantity still 5 instead of it's initial state 1

I would really appreciate the help

this is my state Context code

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";

const Context = createContext();

    export const StateContext = ({ children }) => {
      const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
      const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
      const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);
      const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState(0);
      const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
    
      let foundProduct;
      let index;
    
      const onAdd = (product, quantity) => {
        const checkProductInCart = cartItems.find(
          (item) => item._id === product._id
        );
    
        setTotalPrice(
          (prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice + product.price * quantity
        );
        setTotalQuantities((prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities + quantity);
    
        if (checkProductInCart) {
          const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((cartProduct) => {
            if (cartProduct._id === product._id)
              return {
                ...cartProduct,
                quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity,
              };
    
            if (cartProduct._id === product._id) {
              return {
                ...cartProduct,
                quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity,
              };
            } else {
              return { ...cartProduct };
            }
          });
          setCartItems(updatedCartItems);
        } else {
          product.quantity = quantity;
    
          setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product }]);
        }
    
        toast.success(`${qty} ${product.name} added to the cart.`);
      };
    
      const onRemove = (product) => {
        foundProduct = cartItems.find((item) => item._id === product._id);
        const newCartItems = cartItems.filter((item) => item._id !== product._id);
    
        setTotalPrice(
          (prevTotalPrice) =>
            prevTotalPrice - foundProduct.price * foundProduct.quantity
        );
        setTotalQuantities(
          (prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities - foundProduct.quantity
        );
        setCartItems(newCartItems);
      };
    
      function toggleCartItemQuanitity(id, value) {
        foundProduct = cartItems.find((item) => item._id === id);
        index = cartItems.findIndex((product) => product._id === id);
       
        const newCartItems = cartItems
    
        if (value === "inc") {
          setCartItems(cartItems.map((item) => item._id === id ? { ...foundProduct, quantity: foundProduct.quantity + 1 } : item));
          setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice + foundProduct.price);
          setTotalQuantities((prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities + 1);
        } else if (value === "dec") {
          if (foundProduct.quantity > 1) {
            setCartItems(cartItems.map((item) => item._id === id ? { ...foundProduct, quantity: foundProduct.quantity - 1 } : item));
            setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice - foundProduct.price);
            setTotalQuantities((prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities - 1);
          }
        }
      }
    
      function incQty() {
        setQty((prevQty) => prevQty + 1);
      }
    
      const decQty = () => {
        setQty((prevQty) => {
          if (prevQty - 1 < 1) return 1;
    
          return prevQty - 1;
        });
      };
    
      return (
        <Context.Provider
          value={{
            showCart,
            setShowCart,
            cartItems,
            totalPrice,
            totalQuantities,
            qty,
            incQty,
            decQty,
            onAdd,
            toggleCartItemQuanitity,
            onRemove,
            setCartItems,
            setTotalPrice,
            setTotalQuantities,
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </Context.Provider>
      );
    };
    
    export const useStateContext = () => useContext(Context);
```

Let me know what other part of code should i share

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by setting the quantity back to 1 once the product is added that is if i click add to cart

> toast.success(`${qty} ${product.name} added to the cart.`);
>
> ```
> setQty(1);
> ```

But still there is an issue if i increase the quantity and don't click the add to cart button and load to a different product the value still stays the same and does not revert back to 1

if quantity increased to for example 5 and press add to card { the value sets back to 1 even on the current product }

if quantity increased to 5 and the add to card button is not clicked ( loading to a diff product still holds the value 5 from the previous product selection }

am new to coding and web application and i've been scratching my head since yesterday. can anyone plz guide me where am i going wrong?